# Semantic-UI Special PopUp not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, semantic-ui

I'm trying to build a special pop up with custom html, to add content later to it ...

My console is showing this message = Popup: No visible position could be found for the popup.

```js
$(document)
  .ready(function() {

    $('.item.messages')
      .popup({
        inline: true,
        hoverable: true,
        popup: '.special.popup',
        position: 'bottom left',
        delay: {
          show: 300,
          hide: 800
        }
      });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="item messages">
  <i class="mail icon"></i> 

  <div class="ui special popup">
    <div class="header">Custom Header</div>
    <div class="ui button">Click Me</div>
  </div>

</a>
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: which plugin are you using for the popup?

Comment: are you using [this](http://semantic-ui.com/modules/popup.html) ?

Comment: I'm using only semantic ui and jQuery as its dependency ...

Comment: I've actually found what it might be, it seems the pop up isn't founding space to fit on the screen. I've the component in which he was suposed to show in the middle of the screen, and it appeared.

Answer (score 1):

try this code it will work u need to call div to popup

```
 $(document)
      .ready(function() {

        $('.special.popup')
          .popup({
            inline: true,
            hoverable: true,
            popup: '.special.popup',
            position: 'bottom left',
            delay: {
              show: 300,
              hide: 800
            }
          });
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
setTimeout(function(){
 $('.item.messages')
  .popup({
    inline: true,
    hoverable: true,
    popup: '.special.popup',
    position: 'bottom left',
    delay: {
      show: 300,
      hide: 800
    }
  });

 }, 1000);
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="item messages">
  <i class="mail icon"></i> 
</a>
<div class="ui special popup">
   <div class="header">Custom Header</div>
   <div class="ui button">Click Me</div>
</div>
```

Try this.
In conjuction to Amal's solution above. I believe its better to have the popping div outside the container.

Comment: it doesnt seem to be the problem, its rather the way the popup is initialised (on wrong element as Amal mentioned)